# Power generator (wrong verse)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

This is a very simple Tikz circuit

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) to [V, l={$v$}, i^>={$i$}](0,3) to (3,3) to [R, l={$R$}](3,0) to (0,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

and the results is this one:

[image: Result of the code above]

**QUESTION: Why the power polarity is opposite to the current verse?**

For who do not know electronic: plus and minus must be switched.

But, I do not want write `\draw (0,3) to[V](0,0) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution by using invert

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) to [V, l={$v$},invert, i^>={$i$}](0,3) to (3,3) to [R, l={$R$}](3,0) to (0,0);

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]